# How to create random uuid in a github action

Tags: github-actions

Howdo i create a random uuid from a github action? I found a third party github action that creates a random uuid but i am hoping there is some native action that already supports this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a Linux runner you can use `uuidgen`:

```
name: Test linux job
on:
  push

jobs:
  testJob:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          uuidgen
```

This will output the uuid to the console. You can then redirect the output to a file or a variable with the standard shell mechanisms.

Answer (score 5):

as an improvement to the answer from @riQQ

```
name: Test linux job
on:
  push

jobs:
  testJob:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get uuid
        id: uuid
        run: | 
            echo "::set-output name=uuid::$(uuidgen)"
```